# Oracle: Concatenating grouped rows with filter

Tags: sql, oracle

My data is the following:

```
|ID|Name |LinkType|LinkID | 
|--|-----|--------|-------|
|1 |item1|Task    |12345  | 
|1 |item1|Task    |22347  | 
|1 |item1|Event   |21342  | 
|2 |item2|Task    |24533  | 
|2 |item2|Event   |43532  | 
|2 |item2|Event   |457    |
```

and Im trying to get it to the following format:

```
|ID|Name |Tasks      |Events   |
|--|-----|-----------|---------|
|1 |item1|12345,22347|21342    | 
|2 |item2|24533      |43532,457|
```

I have a working SQL-query, but im wondering, if there is any way to optimize it, as it currently is VERY slow. My dataset is ~800k rows with ~600k unique IDs.

```
SELECT ID
    ,Name
    ,(
        SELECT LISTAGG(Attachments2.LinkID, ',') within
        GROUP (
                ORDER BY Attachments2.LinkID
                ) LinkIDs
        FROM Attachments Attachments2
        WHERE Attachments.ID = Attachments2.ID
            AND LinkType  = 'Task'
        GROUP BY Attachments2.ID
        ) Tasks
    ,(
        SELECT LISTAGG(Attachments3.LinkID, ',') within
        GROUP (
                ORDER BY Attachments3.LinkID
                ) LinkIDs
        FROM Attachments Attachments3
        WHERE Attachments.ID = Attachments3.ID
            AND LinkType = 'Event'
        GROUP BY Attachments3.ID
        ) Events
    
FROM Attachments
GROUP BY ID
    ,Name
```

I total have 4 different LinkType's that I need to do this grouping and this approach is incredibly slow. Im getting 500 results in 5minutes, so getting 600k rows will take too much time.

Comment: Well, key/value tables are a nuisance to work with. `ID` is a bad column name by the way, suggesting it identifies a row, which it does not. It should better be something like `entity_id`, `item_id` or the like, showing that it only identifies an entity, item, whatever. `Name` looks redundant. If ID 1 always has the name 'item1', then this name should reside in the item table or be stored as a key/value with link type 'Name'.  You should have a unique index on `(id, linktype)` of course. Otherwise access will be slow.

Comment: The column names aren't exactly as here, I just paraphrased them to make the example easier. I have no control over the structure.

Comment: The data structure I need is for a migration purposes, so I do need the Name (and other similar things that I didnt add to this example), even though the looks redundant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for conditional aggregation (`CASE WHEN` inside an aggregation function):

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  LISTAGG(CASE WHEN linktype = 'Task' THEN linkid END, ',')
          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY linkid) AS task_ids,
  LISTAGG(CASE WHEN linktype = 'Event' THEN linkid END, ',')
          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY linkid) AS event_ids
FROM attachments
GROUP BY id, name
ORDER BY id, name;
```

You should of course have a unique index on `(id, linktype)`. Make sure it is in that order, i.e. having the item id first followed by the link type, so you can access an item's data quickly. Please also see my other remarks in the comments section of your request.)

Comment: I tried to find if there was a way to filter within the LISTAGG, but didnt find such a example. I will try this as it looks great!